# Achieve table cell effect with floated divs

Tags: html, css, css-tables

If I try to apply `min-width`, `max-width` to a floating div so that it expands to `max-width` when the right content is hidden does not work.

But, if I use table and 2 `td`s in it, the left `td` will expand to 100% if the right `td` is hidden.

Can I achieve this table effect with floated divs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you are asking, but you can make it look like what you are asking.

Make it into two `td`s and put a `max-width` on a `div` inside the `td`. Would that work?

Comment: I may have to go that route. But, I wanted to avoid using tables for layout.

Comment: You could use JavaScript for the layout. If you use overflow:hidden you might be able to use an automatic width or something. But I would not veer away from tables just cause you don't _like_ them. The advanced CSS can be more iffy because of IE. Perhaps edit your question and give some visual examples of what you want and you may get better answers.. I did find the question hard to understand at first.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work with floats. Luckily we now have more tools at our disposal.

Here are two very simple methods to expand a div to 100% of the available width if a sibling horizontally to it is hidden or removed.

### #1 – Using `display: flex`

**Compatibility:** [Edge and all modern browsers.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_display_flex) IE 10 and 11 support the non-standard `-ms-flexbox`.

**The Basic Markup**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    First Column
  </div>
  <div>
    This second column can be hidden or not exist and the first column will take up its space
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

- The container div is given `display: flex`.
- The containers children are give `flex: 1` and they will be assigned equal width, can grow and can shrink.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  background: #FF6961;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #006961;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content takes up the whole width when other divs are hidden.
  </div>
  <div style="display: none">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content takes up the whole width when there is no other div.
  </div>
</div>
```

Read [this guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Read [more about flexbox on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

---

### #2 – Using `display: table`

**Compatibility:** [IE8+ and all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_display_table_values)

**The Basic Markup**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    First Column
  </div>
  <div>
    This second column can be hidden or not exist and the first column will take up its space
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

- The container is given `display: table`
- The containers children are given `display: table-cell` and will act the same as cells in an HTML table. If a cell is hidden or is removed the other cell will take its space.

```css
.container{
  display: table;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container>div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FF6961;
}

.container>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #006961;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content takes up the whole width when other divs are hidden.
  </div>
  <div style="display: none">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content takes up the whole width when there is no other div.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    Content takes up the remaining width if a cell has a fixed width.
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Read [more about CSS tables on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Table)